# Can an app install be triggered solely via a script, without GUI interaction?

Tags: applications, installation, scripts

This current question is indirectly related to the following other question here:
[Checking via a script whether a given app is prohibited from installation on a given device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/255469/checking-via-a-script-whether-a-given-app-is-prohibited-from-installation-on-a-g)

I'm running stock rooted Android 11 and stock rooted Android 13 on two different devices.

I'm wondering if there's a way that I could write a script that runs on the Android device and which will install a given app from the Play Store.

My goal is to initiate the app installation from the Android device without any GUI interaction; *i.e.*, no clicks nor button presses nor any manual operations, and I want this to be able to be accomlished solely within a script that gets executed on the device.

In the other question I referred to above, I found out that a slightly different Play-Store-related operation could not be invoked in this way, and that the only way it could be accomplished on the device itself is via GUI interaction ... either manually or via some sort of "uiautomator"-like automation.

Is this the same situation here? *i.e.*, is it impossible when running on the device to install any app from the Play Store without some sort of GUI interaction?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The thing you are trying to avoid is 'user authorization' but stock Android wants that for security / anti-malware reasons. On non-root stock devices, Mobile Device Management (MDM) services like Samsung Knox/Microsoft Intune can force push apps to devices under mgmt. If you are okay with side-loading APK rather than Play Store installed see: [How to Install the APK package automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29825028/295004) and https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=install+app+as+system+app . Do think about how two different devices are talking if not via Play Store site.

Comment: Thank you. Sideloading is usually fine. I just was hoping that there might also have been some sort of "Play Store API" that could be used to perform the same functions on the device that the gui-based Play Store interaction implements. Such an API could have access to the same MDM services as the manual gui. But I guess I'm out of luck with that.

Comment: And yes, I know about copying the APK to the appropriate place under /data/app, and also, thank you for pointing me to that intent. I was just wondering if such an installation could also be performed without the APK file having previously been downloaded ... just like the way the Play Store does it. The Play Store first downloads and then installs, and that's what I was hoping to be able to do via some sort of shell script. But again, I now see that I can't do that.

Comment: While not from the Play Store, I remember there was a question about compiling and installing an app from open-source repos directly from the Android terminal, but it seems I missed it now...

Comment: Maybe this can be suitably modified https://github.com/aniketkatkar/GPlay-App-AutoInstaller?tab=readme-ov-file

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. I'll check this out. It's meant to use adb, which means that it (or at least part of it) runs outside of the device itself. But yes, I will see if there might be a way to suitably modify it to run totally within the device to perform what I'm hoping to perform.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Google itself shows you the way. If you are logged in a web browser with your Google account you can initiate app installations on all of your devices, so there is an API to initiate the download (calling it directly with the proper cookies). Or you use Selenium or a similar web test system which can even run without UI once you have automated it. Third there is AuroraStore and GPlayAPI. But I don't know if the API included the API form installing apps on different device of your account is available in GPlayAPI project (AFAIR this function is available in Goofle Play Store app).